# x86 NASM 'org' directive meaning

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I am following this tutorial as a first foray into bootloader/OS development for x86 using NASM:

http://joelgompert.com/OS/TableOfContents.htm

And I'm on Lesson 4, which is making my bootloader print the "Hello, world" string.
I'm not understanding the meaning of the `org` instruction (directive?).

As I understand it, `org` defines where the program being executed is loaded into memory. This is needed when using any sort of labels or relative addresses in the program.

Suppose I have a string defined with a label like this in my program:

```
szHello db 'Hello, world!', 0
```

And I then later try to reference that label like this (only relevant snippets):

```
org 0x7c00
xor ax, ax
mov ds, 0
...
mov si, szHello
lodsb
...
int 0x10 ; Print first character of szHello
```

My question is, why is that not equivalent to this? :

```
org 0
mov ds, 0x7c00
...
mov si, szHello
lodsb
...
int 0x10
```

When I run the first example, my string appears correctly. The second example does not work.

Pointers to relevant documentation would also be greatly appreciated, if the issue is a conceptual problem on my part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

0000:7C00 is not equivalent to 7C00:0000. The segment part is counted in paragraphs, not bytes. Try this instead:

```
mov ax, 0x7c0 
mov ds, ax
```

Comment: Excellent, that works, thank you. However, I'm not sure I fully understand. Does `org` consume a segment address, or an offset into a segment?

Comment: It's an offset in the current segment.

Comment: `mov ds, 0x7c0` is not a valid instruction. Maybe you mean something like `mov ax, 0x7c0` `mov ds, ax`

Answer (score 21):

`org` defines where the program in question EXPECTS to be loaded into memory.  Not where it actually is loaded -- that is controlled by whoever does the loading -- but where it expects to be loaded.

Comment: Interesting. What happens to my program if it's loaded somewhere else? And then, why does `org` exist at all?

Comment: If it's loaded somewhere else, the offsets calculated by the assembler (such as the address of the szHello label) will be wrong and what happens next is anyone's guess.