# NASM org instruction vs. linker script

Tags: x86, linker, nasm, ld, bootloader

I have been using a linker script for a simple kernel I made, and although the linking process always confused me a bit, it has been working fine.

Now that I started working on a simple bootloader for the kernel, I found that many examples use `org 0x7C00` when assembling with `nasm -f bin ...`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140016/x86-nasm-org-directive-meaning) question, which I think helped me understand (along with nasm's documentation) what it's used for: Specifying where the program is going to be loaded, so nasm can calculate addresses correctly.

From this, I started to wonder if using:

```
org 0x7C00
section .text
global _start
_start:
    ...
```

Is the same as not using that `org` directive and linking with the following linker script.

```c
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x7C00;

    .text : AT(0x7C00) {
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

I can immediately see that the second binary is 4040 bytes instead of 512. If I open the resulting binaries with [rizin](https://rizin.re/), I can see that the address on the prompt is `0x0` for the first one, and `0x7C00` for the second one. Why does this happen?

I tried running both versions, and the second doesn't seem to work, probably because the magic 0xAA55 value is not even on the right place.

Comment: You might want to examine both binaries with objdump/hexdump to see where the differences are.

Comment: The second binary has your MBR wrapped by ELF metadata.  You'd need `objcopy` to extract it, or tell `ld` to make a flat binary instead of an ELF executable.

Comment: @mkayaalp I already examined them with hexdump, and the first one was just the assembled instructions and the padding for the 512 byte signature. The second one had much more stuff that I couldn't understand.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see, thank you. The outputs of `file ...` are also different. However, now I am wondering: Apart from the different executable format, does the `. = 0x7C00` line specify something different from the `org 0x7C00` line in NASM?

Comment: Those accomplish the same thing.  `org 0x7c00` with `nasm -f bin` tells NASM's built-in "linker" how to fill in absolute addresses, the same way that `. = 0x7C00` tells `ld` to fill in the relocation entries in the `.o` produced by `nasm -f elf32` or whatever object-file format you used.